# Angular 11 app hosted in IIS giving CORS issue when calling Asp.Net Web API

Tags: asp.net, angular, ssl, cors

We have the following setup

**Angular 11 / TypeScript app**: Hosted in IIS with SSL/TLS cert (**HTTPS**) and sending user credentials (NTLM) to the backend API using withCredentials header.
Also for CORS we are passing header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'

**Asp.Net Web API (.Net 6)**: Self-hosted using Http.Sys (to support NTLM) and using **HTTP**.
To support CORS, we are using this

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(b => b.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials()));
```

When the Angular App is making a call to the backend API, it is getting error related to CORS.

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

But when we run Angular app without SSL/TLS cert i.e HTTP, then it works fine.

So this CORS issue, is it happening because Angular app is HTTPS and backend API is HTTP? If yes then how can we solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add cors on the middleware too?

Comment: @EkhlasMridha: Not sure what you are asking. But .UseCors() is used in the code.

Answer (score 0):

> So this CORS issue, is it happening because Angular app is HTTPS and backend API is HTTP? If yes then how can we solve this issue?

The mismatch of TLS to non-TLS requests throws something like this:

> Access to fetch at 'https://another-site.com/' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

You are getting this error because the preflight OPTIONS request is being redirected by some sort of Middleware routing (I assume).

You can read up on how to configure for OPTIONS preflight requests here. There is lots of options depending on your requirements, so I won't post a suggestion.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#preflight-requests